# Is a +/- 10-15 rpm idle fluctuation normal?

Tags: engine, honda, civic, rough-idle, idle

98 Honda civic ex

I'm curious if during idle, it's normal for the rpms to fluctuate 10-15 rpms +/- or if it's supposed to always be steady constantly?

My OEM tach doesn't pick up this slight change so it looks steady there, but with my obd2 scan tool I can see it.

Is that normal? I've been trying to tackle a slight engine shake at idle but everyone's been telling me it's normal just want to get more opinions. Thanks

Comment: It is fairly normal while idling. Does it jump when you shift in to gear?

Comment: It is fairly normal while idling. Does it jump when you shift in to gear?

Comment: Jump? Not that I notice. It's a manual transmission

Answer (score 4):

Completely normal. Nothing to worry about

Comment: So is the idle ever completely steady/constant on any car or they have this slight fluctuation as well?

Comment: Every car I ever checked especially with a digital meter will alway fluctuate.  You should see when you use a graph. It's never a steady line.

Comment: To the OP: Most of the dash gauges give a stead state readout, yet if you were to look at them digitally as you are the RPMs, you'd notice they jump around a little bit. Nothing is ever at a completely steady state. It's more like a little tug of war going on, with the ECU doing it's best to keep everything in check, but never keeping it perfect.